# In Aurelia, is there a good way to swap out a custom control at run time?

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia, is there a good way to swap out a custom element at run time?

My use case is a control that will be used in several places, but a user may want to swap out how the given control is rendered and behaves. I currently have an InlineViewStrategy that renders views from strings, but this has the disadvantage of not being able to control bindings and such within the view model. Can I pick a view model at run time to use, and can I allow users to register new custom controls they build themselves to use instead of those that are there by default?

So, I'm building a grid:

https://github.com/jeremeevans/EspalierJS

The cell is using an InlineViewStrategy:

https://github.com/jeremeevans/EspalierJS/blob/master/src/grid/espalier-cell.ts

And the views are defined in a Map in config:

https://github.com/jeremeevans/EspalierJS/blob/master/src/grid/espalier-config.ts

This is ugly because it doesn't let the end user customize behavior of the cells to a high enough degree, and generally cripples templating. It's not great for performance, either.

I would prefer to put custom control definitions in there and allow the user build a whole control to go into a cell.

Comment: it's possible but it's very hard to say something without seeing some code. Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @FabioLuz Thanks for the reply; I have added more detail and links to the repository. I'd really like to figure out what the best approach there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was able to increase performance a lot, especially in IE11, by switching from using Compose to using cached view factories, and rendering the views from those view factories.

I have a static map of string to ViewFactory and build the view factories as needed, then bind the view factory to the cell view:

`<td colspan="${(!settings.getButtons && $index == (settings.columns.length - 1)) ? 2 : 1}" repeat.for="column of settings.columns & oneTime">
            <espalier-cell column.bind="column" view.bind="column.view" record.bind="record"></espalier-cell>
          </td>`

```
    import { IEspalierDataFormatter } from "./espalier-data-formatter";
    import { IColumnDefinition } from "./column-definition";
    import { bindable, customElement, inject, noView, ViewSlot, ViewFactory, Container } from "aurelia-framework";
    import { ColumnType } from "./enums";

```
@customElement("espalier-cell")
@noView()
@inject(ViewSlot, Container)
export class EspalierCell {
  @bindable
  public column: IColumnDefinition<any>;

  @bindable
  public record: any;

  @bindable
  public view: ViewFactory;

  protected data: any;
  private isAttached = false;

  constructor(private viewSlot: ViewSlot, private container: Container) { }

  protected attached() {
    this.isAttached = true;
    this.loadView();
  }

  protected viewChanged() {
    if (this.isAttached) {
      this.loadView();
    }
  }

  private loadView() {
    const propertyValue = this.record[this.column.propertyName];
    this.data = (<IEspalierDataFormatter>this.column.dataFormatter).format(propertyValue, this.record);
    let view = this.view.create(this.container);
    view.bind(this);
    this.viewSlot.add(view);
    this.viewSlot.attached();
  }
}
```

```